# mysql get max value with multiple choices

Tags: php, mysql

i have this poll thing, Poll A, has 3 options let's say: Option a option b option c, option a got 3 votes, option b got 2 votes option c got 3 votes,

```
    OPTIONS     VOTES 
    option a       3
    option b       2
    option c       3
```

and i have this mysql query which gets the options and orders by votesCount, limit 1 to get the top answer, but in my example, there are two options on top, they both have the highest values, i want a query to get those two options, n not only one, so i have to get rid of LIMIT 1

Mysql query is

```
$query = "SELECT `option` FROM `options` WHERE `pid` = '$pid' AND `votesCount` != '0' ORDER BY `votesCount` DESC LIMIT 1";
```

any suggestion?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(votes) ...`

Comment: @yvytty i thought that there is a one mysql query for that, cuz i can remove the limit and do with php, that was the main question, asking for a mysql query if it exists

Comment: @yvytty thanks, i used one of the answers here, i appreciate your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gordon Linoff for the hint, this is how it is now

```
$query = "SELECT `option` FROM `options` WHERE `pid` = '$pid' AND `votesCount` = (SELECT MAX(`votesCount`) FROM `options` WHERE `pid` = '$pid' ORDER BY `votesCount` DESC LIMIT 1)";
    ///Just a DB function, don't mind the 0, i'm using a class
    $res = $db->get_rows($db->select($query),0);
    $merged = array();
    foreach ($res as $r){
        $merged[] = $r->option;
    }
    $merged = implode(',',$merged);
    return $merged;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a standard way in any SQL dialect:

```
select p.*
from poll p
where p.votes = (select max(votes) from poll)
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, it worked like that :SELECT `option` FROM `options` WHERE `pid` = '$pid' AND `votesCount` !='0' AND `votesCount` = (SELECT MAX(`votesCount`) FROM `options` WHERE `pid` = '$pid' ORDER BY `votesCount` DESC LIMIT 1)